# How does form tracking code work that is NOT Google related?

Tags: javascript

I work for a marketing agency and am building a custom marketing dashboard. As a part of our core product, I need to create a custom web form tracking script that I can embed on a clients web page to track their form submissions. This is similar to what Google Analytics provides however, I need to write my own. When searching Google, I only get results pertaining to GTM or Google Analytics which obviously don't explain how the code actually works.

So far I have been able to establish a connection with the form when the page loads by providing the name of the form in an array that's passed to the tracking script using an immediately invoked function. In the script, I attach to the 'onsubmit' event of that form and send the values to a custom API endpoint function however, that overwrites the submit event that may already be in place. This cannot happen in case a client we are attempting to track form submissions for already has something else in place they need to submit to. In other words, the tracking code cannot be invasive at all and should hook up to existing forms. I know there is a better approach I could just use some guidance going forward.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
      var _mxtr_ = _mxtr_ || [];
      _mxtr_.push(['endpoint', 'uuid_for_instance']);
      _mxtr_.push(['form', 'test-form']);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="mxtr_ts.js">
((mxtr) => {
window.onload = () => {
document.forms[mxtr[1][1]].onsubmit = (ev) => {
  //preventDefault is causing the problems but without it, the form doesn't submit
  ev.preventDefault();
  let url = 'custom api endpoint';
  let sendData = {};
  let formData = [...document.forms[mxtr[1][1]]];

  console.log('FORM DATA', formData);

  for (const i of formData) {
    //Below will grab form data preferrably by name if not, then ID which could be randomly generated
    sendData[i.name ? i.name : i.id] = i.value
  }

  function getCookie(cname) {
    let name = cname + '=';
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');

    for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      let c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return 'NA';
  }

  let m_id = getCookie('mtc_id');

  axios.post(url + mxtr[0][1], sendData)
    .then((res, err) => {
      console.log('RESULT', res, 'ERROR', err);
      if (!err) {
        document.getElementById('form-response').innerText = 'Success';
        mxtr = null;
        // document.forms[mxtr[1][1]].submit();
      } else {
        document.getElementById('form-response').innerText = 'Error';
        mxtr = null;
      }
    });
   }
  };
})(_mxtr_);

</script>
```

I would like to get that form data to the endpoint so I can process it accordingly. Perhaps a better idea of how current tracking code works is what I need so I can come up with a better approach that does not affect the current submission of the form. Any help provided is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seriously.. why down vote with no explanation?! Why?!

Comment: Maybe they found it was not specific enough.. nowadays the world's became hard; a lot of people avoid commenting to prevent retaliation from the OP or just because they're bored to repeat the same things.. don't get too upset about one specific vote, life's short

Comment: Wow, thank you. I really appreciate that. I've learned that I need to be descriptive on SO and thought I was but you're probably right. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of these javascript function is that they are unique, by setting one, you replace the previous. You could run into the same problem with `window.onload`.

One solution is to save the previous handlers and call them yourself, like this:

This can be done for the submit function too.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  console.log('onload one set by user');
};

(function(myFramework){
  var load = window.onload;
  
  window.onload = function(){
    console.log('onload two set by ' + myFramework);
    
    if(load){
      load();
    }
  };
})('theBestFrameworkInTheUnknownUniverse');
```

Comment: So when 'load()' gets called in the IIF, will that wont trigger it twice? I appreciate the reply btw.

Comment: no, because you replaced it by your own. The snippet demonstrates that: if you don't call it, the first user `onload` is not fired at all.

Comment: Got it! I will give that a shot. Thanks a lot for the help! I might be back :)

Comment: I have gotta say, your suggestion has definitely got me on the right track so thank you. I was however curious how form validation would affect this. Would my script be called before any form validation takes place? For example, suppose someone didn't fill in a required field, would my submit handler be called prior to that validation happening? Let me know when you can and again, i really appreciate your help.

Comment: @ZacHerman it depends on where you place the manual call to the user function. You can do things before, after, or both. Note that you should transmit the event object and arguments the handler received to the user function, and because it's passed by reference, you should be able to read transformations made to it by the user function, like if it was prevented with `preventDefault` for example